# Optimizing and clarifying nested list appending

Tags: python, optimization

I have such part in my script, how can I optimize such parts?  I don't want to use many local variables.

```
size_variants = []
for size in sizes_list:
    size_variants.append({'size': size})
```

Also here:

```
variants_tmp = list()
all_color_list = list(get_all_colors())
[variants_tmp.extend(var) for var in all_color_list]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a list comprehension means you can eliminate all local variables:

```
size_variants = [{'size': size} for size in sizes_list]
```

Generally, anything of the form:

```
<new list initialization>
for <variable> in <list>:
    <new list>.append(<variable>)
```

can be written much more cleanly in list comprehension form.

Edit: If you want to extend an already existing list, and you have something like a nested list, then you'll probably want to use `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [[4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]
x = x + [i for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(y)]
```

which will have `x == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Comment: but what if I need not to append, but extend?

Comment: @user: You can still use a list comprehension, since `extend` takes a generator too.

Comment: @Hurkyl i`m trying but it is crashing here:
        variants_tmp = list()
        all_color_list = list(get_all_colors())
        [variants_tmp.extend(var) for var in all_color_list]

Comment: @user: nono, you pass the generator expression *into* `extend`, not call `extend` in the generator expression.

Comment: @Hurkyl still dont understand, sorry :(

Comment: @user2734570 See my edit.